# Adding orientation in the Android Manifest is not working [React-Native]

Tags: android, react-native

I'm actually using Ignite 2.0 for my react-native application. 
I would like to lock the application in portrait mode but even if I write this in my android manifest, it doesn't work :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.faceapplication"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

If someone have an answer it will be great ! Thanks for all !

Answer (score 0):

Add this `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` line in all activity declarations.

Comment: I add it in the other activity but nothing changes :/

Comment: Any other ideas?